# Proof of Menelaus using areas

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area, ratio

I've tried to proof *Menelaus' theorem* using areas, but I've didn't figure out how. Some suggestions would be appreciated.

Menelaus' Theorem states :

> [image]
>
> Given a triangle ABC and a  transversal line that crosses BC, AC and
>   AB at points D, E and F respectively, with D, E and F distinct from A,
>   B and C, then :
>
> $$\frac{AF}{FB} * \frac{BD}{DC} * \frac{CE}{EA} = 1 $$

So far, I've proved Van Aubel's and Ceva's Theorem using areas, but I got stuck at Menelaus.

First, I taught $\frac{[ACB]}{[BCF]} = \frac {AB}{BF}$. And I've applied this for few more triangles, but it didn't work.

(I've noted with $[ABC]$ the area of triangle ABC).

Thanks!

Comment: I am sure you can find plenty of proofs on the internet..

Comment: Search, in particular, for Grunbaum & Shephard's "Ceva, Menelaus, and the Area Principle" (*Mathematics Magazine*, Vol. 68, No. 4. (Oct., 1995), pp. 254-268) for the definitive treatment of this approach.

Comment: @Blue Thank you, I'll keep it in mind